# Why isnt my snake printing to the screen?

Tags: c, pointers, raylib

I'm writing snake using raylib and C yet m snake is not printing to the screen , Why?

```
#include "raylib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CELLSIZE 30
#define CELLCOUNT 25

Color green = {173, 204, 96, 255};
Color darkGreen = {43, 51, 24, 255};

typedef struct{
        int orit;
        Vector2 pos;
} cells;

int main(void){
        unsigned int Size = 3;

        cells* snake = malloc(sizeof * snake * Size);

        snake[0].pos.x = 6;
        snake[0].pos.y = 9;
        snake[1].pos.x = 5;
        snake[1].pos.y = 9;
        snake[2].pos.x = 4;
        snake[2].pos.y = 9;

        InitWindow(CELLSIZE * CELLCOUNT, CELLSIZE * CELLCOUNT, "retro snake");
        SetTargetFPS(60);

        Vector2 foodPos = {
                GetRandomValue(0, CELLCOUNT - 1),
                                             
        while (!WindowShouldClose())
        {
                BeginDrawing();
                ClearBackground(green);

                DrawRectangle(foodPos.x * CELLSIZE, foodPos.y * CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE, darkGreen);

                for (unsigned int i; i < Size; i++){

                        DrawRectangle(snake[i].pos.x * CELLSIZE, snake[i].pos.y * CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE, darkGreen);
                }

                EndDrawing();
        }

        CloseWindow();
        free(snake);

        return 0;
}
```

Its really confusing, i was expecting it to be printed to the screen but all i get is this:

[as you can see, the food prints yet the snake doesnt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbtsY.png)

I also use pointers as my snakes size is variable

Comment: I haven't used raylib, but in your pointer assignment statement "cells* snake = malloc(sizeof * snake * Size);", you are trying to allocate memory on the size of the pointer variable "snake".  I think you want to allocate memory on the size of the "cells" structure with a statement like "cells* snake = malloc(sizeof (cells) * Size);"

Comment: @NoDakker `sizeof` operates on *expressions*: `sizeof (*snake) == sizeof (cells)` - that is the *type* of the *expression* `*snake` is `cells`.

Comment: `unsigned int i` is uninitialized, containing an indeterminate representation. `i < Size` invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). Initialize the variable: `unsigned int i = 0`. Effectively a typo.

Comment: Additionally, the initializer for `foodPos` is incomplete in this example. Please make sure you are posting verified [mre]s.

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned int i could be anything since in C variables don`t have a default value like in Java. So it could be anything.
You have to initialize i to 0.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
    DrawRectangle(snake[i].pos.x * CELLSIZE, snake[i].pos.y * CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE, darkGreen);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your loop in the main function. Specifically, you're missing the initialization of the loop counter variable, `i`. Without initializing `i`, the loop behavior is undefined, and it may not execute as you expected it to.

```c
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
    DrawRectangle(snake[i].pos.x * CELLSIZE, snake[i].pos.y * CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE, darkGreen);
}
```

Here we initialized `i = 0`, so that the loop will start from the first index and display the segments of the snake.